# F# join string option list

Tags: f#

How do I concatenate a list of string option?

```
let m = [ ""; "12"; "a"; "b"] 
// I can join these with 
m |> List.toSeq |> String.concat "\n" 

// now I got a list of string option list 
let l = [Some ""; None; Some "a"; Some "b"] 
l |> List.toSeq |> ????
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you first use [List.choose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353456.aspx) to "extract" the Some values of the list :

```
l |> List.choose id |> String.concat "\n"
```

Note you don't need `List.toSeq` as seq is an alias for [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and ['t list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370372.aspx) implement it already.